# Html.Beginform forcing addition of controller name

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4, using

```
Html.BeginForm("/", null, FormMethod.Post, new{something="demo"})
```

the resulting form has

```
action="//"
```

Because it is apparently trying to squeeze the controller and action into the url. However, I'm using the HomeController as the default controller, so I don't want /Home/action in the url. This has been working fine in most places, but this form seems to be tripping me up

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to use @Html markup? You can write pure html <form action="/" ...> and here mvc controls </form>

Comment: the form has client-side validation, so trying to keep the @html route. Plus, I just need to figure out how to do it this way

Answer (score 2):

That's not the controller name.  You would do something like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {something="demo"})
```

If your routes are setup correctly and Home/Index is your default root route, then when rendered, it will render to "/".  MVC will automatically optimize the route to show the default minimum (which is the lone "/")

If your not seeing "/" then look at your routes, as it's not able to reverse generate the URL correctly (probably more than one route matches).

If you are using Home/SomethingElse and it's not the default route, then I don't quite get what you're trying to do, since you would be required to specify the Controller/Action to post to it.

While I don't recommend it, you should also be able to do this:

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {action="/", something="demo"})
```

I would consider this a hack, however, and I would encourage you to fix the actual route problem.

Comment: manually adding the action per your "not recommended" method was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: using the null or even "" in the controller name, with a "/" for the action name, resulted in a path of "/". Even though "home" is my default route, I assumed both "/" and "/Home" would both resolve, and thus putting "Home" in the controller name would result in the not-desired fully qualified version.

Comment: @boomhauer - you need to be more clear about what you want.  Your question seemed to want a path of "/".  Please clarify.

Comment: I think my comment didn't take correctly. what I meant was it resulted in a path of "//", not the "/" that I wanted.

Comment: @boomhauer - I repeat.  If your routes are setup correctly, and Home/Index is your default route, then specifying `BeginForm("Index", "Home")` will render the action a single "/".